How to prevent duplicates from being written to .txt file
I'm trying to write code that will prevent a duplicate user name from being written to file.
In my latest iteration so far, I've managed to get duplicates of the first key rejected, but duplicates of subsequent keys are still going through. I.e if my keys have the values 'admin' and 'user' (which I've confirmed in my first print statement), x = admin is rightly being rejected but x = users is still progressing.
My code:
alr_exists = {}
user = {} 
with open('user.txt', 'r') as file: 
    for lines in file:
        (keys, values) = lines.split()
        keys = keys.replace(',', '')
        alr_exists[keys] = keys
        print(alr_exists[keys])

        while True: 
            x = input("To register a new user, please enter a username:\n").lower()
            if x in alr_exists[keys]:
                print(f'Sorry, the user name {x} has already been taken. Please try again.\n')
                continue
            else:
                y = input("Please enter a password:\n").lower()
                z = input("To confirm, please reenter your password:\n").lower()

Sample data set:
admin, adm1n
user, us3r

(Where the first column contains user names and the second passwords.)

maybe you are looking for if x in alr_exists.keys()

the key doesn't exist in alr_exists you should add it inside the else clause.

Can you please provide a small sample dataset and what your expected output would be? What are the keys and values here? Are keys "roles" and values "usernames"? That seems to be how you're using them, but it's hard to tell.

Your while loop should be outside of the file loop. Otherwise, you're only reading one line / checking one key

You could use a set rather than a dict for this.   Otherwise, see @Elerium115 comment.  And OneCricketeer too

I think you want to unindent your while loop two levels

while loop should be same level as of  with statment

I hope you are enjoying programming with Python. I’m new here too.
Looking at your code I see three things that can make it not work:

You have a while loop that is infinite, and that, according to the indentation, is also inside the for loop that reads line by line. There are things that can go within the cycles, and others that are unnecessary and lend themselves to making mistakes.
You are storing existing usernames in a dictionary, but it has both a key and a value for the username, perhaps you could use a list or assign another value to each key such as True/False or the password.
You are checking if the user already exists by comparing it with the value of the last iteration, in your code you are not accessing the keys but the value (username) of the last line of the file. if x in alr_exists[keys]:
You could use the dict.keys() function in your case if x in alr_exists.keys()

I propose a modified version of your code, and I hope it does not seem complicated to you, it is also commented and follows the style of pep8.
def read_existing_usernames(filename):
    """Read existing usernames from a file and store them in a dictionary.

    Args:
        filename (str): The name of the file containing existing usernames.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary containing existing usernames as keys.
    """
    # Create an empty dictionary to store existing usernames
    existing_usernames = {}
    
    # Read existing usernames from the file
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        # Iterate over each line in the file
        for line in file:
            # Split the line into username and password (separated by a space)
            username, _ = line.split()
            
            # Store the username in the dictionary and set the value to True
            existing_usernames[username] = True
    
    # Print a success message with the existing usernames
    print(f'Existing usernames: {', '.join(existing_usernames)}')
    
    # Return the dictionary of existing usernames
    return existing_usernames


def register_user():
    """
    Register a new user by entering a username and password.
    The username must be unique and the password must be confirmed.
    The new username and password are stored in a file. ('user.txt')
    
    Args:
        None
        
    Returns:
        None
    """
    # Bring in existing usernames from the file with the function
    existing_usernames = read_existing_usernames('user.txt')
    
    # Iterate until a new user is successfully registered
    while True:
        # Prompt the user to enter a new username
        username = input("To register a new user, please enter a username: ")
        
        # Check if the username is already taken
        if username.lower() in existing_usernames:
            # Print an error message and prompt the user to try again
            print(f"Sorry, the username '{username}' has already been taken")
            print("Please try again.\n")
        # If the username is not taken
        else:
            # Prompt the user to enter a password and confirm it
            password = input("Please enter a password: ")
            
            # Confirm the password by reentering it
            confirm_password = input("Please reenter your password: ")
            
            # Check if the passwords match
            if password == confirm_password:
                # Open the file in append mode and write the new information
                # Append because we don't want to overwrite the existing data
                with open('user.txt', 'a') as file:
                    # Write the new username and password to the file
                    file.write(f'{username} {password}\n')
                
                # Print a success register message
                print("User registered successfully!")
                
                # Break out of the loop to end the program
                break
            
            # If the passwords do not match
            else:
                # Print an error message and prompt the user to try again
                print("Passwords do not match. Please try again.\n")

# Run main program to register a new user
register_user()


Thank you! Appreciate it not just the answer, but that you took the time to explain where exactly I went wrong

It has a small error and that is that you are requesting a new username in each iteration of the for loop, which is not necessary.
Below you can see the correction by modifying the code you provided very little.
alr_exists = {}
user = {}

with open('user.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        key, _ = line.strip().split(',')
        alr_exists[key.strip()] = True

while True:
    new_username = input("To register a new user, please enter a username:\n").strip().lower()
    if new_username in alr_exists:
        print(f'Sorry, the user name {new_username} has already been taken. Please try again.\n')
    else:
        password = input("Please enter a password:\n").strip().lower()
        user[new_username] = password
        print("User registered successfully!")
        break


This code should do the work:
# setting username
while True:
    x = input("username?")
    if x in keys:
        continue
    break
# setting password
while True:
    x = input("password?")
    ...   

